# What is wrong with this python program? (Traceback error)

Tags: python

my question is why isn't my program working in python 3, It appears to be triggered in the "Speed=dist/time section. Your help would be appreciated.
If you could also correct it would be very helpful.

```
Illegal=[]
Legal=[]
Count = 0
DIST = 0
TIME = 0
SPEED = 0

def CalSpeed():
    global SPEED
    SPEED=DIST/TIME
    return SPEED

print (" Welcome to the Speed check calculator by Awiar Nasseri")
print ("\n")

Count=int(input("How many registration numbers are there?: "))
LIMIT=int(input ("Speed limit (M/S): "))
VAR=int(input ("How many (M/S) should be allowed over the limit?: "))
LIMIT=LIMIT+VAR

while Count > 0:
    Count=Count-1
    REG = input ("Enter Registration number: ")
    TIME =int (input("Enter the time that the vehicle was in the zone in seconds (e.g. 1min= 60)"))
    DIST = input ("Distance inside the zone (M): ")
    SPEED=(DIST/TIME)

    if SPEED>LIMIT:
      Illegal.append(REG)

    elif SPEED<LIMIT:
        Legal.append(REG)

print ("Press P to print illegal and legal cars or press nothing to exit: ")
if option=="P":
    print (Legal[0])
    print (Illegal[0])
print("Thank you for using the program, Goodbye")
sys.exit(0)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\bhs-students\1515787\Desktop\assess.py", line 26, in <module>
    SPEED=(DIST/TIME)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: Can  you provide the  error returned by the execution of this program ?

Comment: Please provide the error you receive. Closing as unclear until then.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\bhs-students\1515787\Desktop\assess.py", line 26, in <module>
    SPEED=(DIST/TIME)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: `DIST` is a string, convert it to an int/float as well.

Comment: post error in question not comments

Comment: just corrected it harwee, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line no 26 to

```
DIST = int(input ("Distance inside the zone (M): "))
SPEED=(DIST/float(TIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting the DIST variable to an Int, meaning that if fails as it can't divide a string by an int.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error is indicating, you cannot divide a string by an int. You need to convert your input to a numeric type

```
DIST = float(input("Distance inside the zone (M): "))
```